# Booting to a black screen

Tags: boot, graphic-drivers, drivers

I just installed elementary os. Works perfect. Installed some updates and programs, hit restart and every thing works.
Installed the videocard drivers  (AMD hd 7850), moved all my music and photos to the pc. Hit restart and boot in to a black screen...

When I hit the powerpoint button

- bios loads
- elementary logo
- screen fills with white letters for couple off seconds
- black screen

I can not get into the OS. But when I hit the powerpoint button again to shuttle it off I see the elementary logo again.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+F1 or F2